# How to add this complex query into CDbCriteria (Yii 1.x)

Tags: mysql, yii, frameworks

I am trying to run the following query but run this through Yii's own CDbCriteria so it can work alongside some other queries that are using the Yii CDbCriteria functionality.

I'm not sure how i'd do the following SQL query using the CDbCriteria can anyone assist?

```
SELECT *
FROM
students t1
WHERE school_id = 1 
AND
(
    SELECT
        sum(points)
    FROM
        students t2
    WHERE
        t2.id <= t1.id
) >= 1000
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the use of CDbCriteria is not mandatory for others reason, 
when a sql is complex you can use `findAllBySql(..)`

```
$models=Students::model()->findAllBySql(
       "SELECT * FROM students t1
         WHERE school_id = 1 
         AND ( SELECT  sum(points)
         FROM    students t2
         WHERE    t2.id <= t1.id ) >= 1000
         ORDER BY id
         LIMIT 1" 
);
```

Comment: Quite correct, but does not directly answer the question. The OP said "...so it can work alongside some other queries that are using the Yii CDbCriteria functionality ..."